# How to draw line with texture instead of color?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have lot of sprites on screen ( cars looking from top ) and I am drawing polylines ( like call  `ccDrawPoly(redBlue, 8, false)` ). I need to replace line color with texture ( I have image of water and I want to draw line with water texture  `water.png` ).
How to make this ?

Comment: a line can't have a texture, you want to draw a textured polygon. This needs to be done with OpenGL because cocos2d-x has no such generic texture drawing functionality

Answer (score 1):

PaolaJ, I could suggest a hack

- Create Sprite Object
- Give it some width like 2,4,8 or 16 (depending on your texture)
- Sprite Height could be same as line length.
- Use sprite->getTexture()->setTexParameters({GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT}) to repeat your texture.
- use rotation to place the sprite properly.
- make sure texture is power of 2.

On the other hand, proper way would be textured polygon as LearnCocos2d suggested.